# Using 'post_type' => 'product' in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a woocomemce site and the products have a "manufacturer" attribute.

when i get the terms for a single product :

```
  $terms= get_the_terms($product->id,"pa_manufacturer");
```

i get :

```
Array ( [230] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 230 [name] => Dadawan [slug] => dadawan       [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 230 [taxonomy] => pa_manufacturer [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 4 [object_id] => 2905 ) )
```

Can i do a loop WP_query only with that term_id to get products with the same manufacturer?
How can i get only the products with that specific term_id?

here is my test, but not working...

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'product',
'term_id'       => 230 ,
'posts_per_page' => 2,
'orderby' => $orderby   
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

// Do stuff here to display your products
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in your query. Term_id is not available argument for WP_Query. Here is a list of available arguments. I got the list from http://phporlando.com/wp_query-argument-list/

```
attachment
attachment_id
author
author_name
cat
category__and
category__in
category__not_in
category_name
comments_popup
day
error
feed
hour
minute
monthnum
name
order
orderby
page_id
page
paged
pagename
post__in
post__not_in
post_status
post_type
preview
robots
sentence
second
static
subpost
subpost_id
tag__and
tag__in
tag__not_in
tag_id
tag_slug__and
tag_slug__in
tag
taxonomy - (pre 3.1)
tb
term - (pre 3.1)
w
withcomments
withoutcomments
year

Pre WP 3.1

meta_key
meta_value

Since WP 3.1

fields
meta_query
tax_query
```